# Browser displays IP rather than name

Tags: apache, dns, lamp

I just built a web page and made it live.  The web page was previously accessible by its IP address.  I then went to godaddy and made a domain name forward to the IP.   The problem is that once I get to the page, the web browser displays the IP rather than the domain name.  The customer wants the domain name to display on the page along with the page itself.  Most companies want their .com name on the browser bar.

Example: On this page, my browser displays `stackoverflow.com/question/ask` rather than the Server's ip address.

The web page is served by apache and the server OS is a Bitnami LAMP server.

Any advice?  And what else should I do to register and make a domain name function properly?

Comment: is there somewhere in a file where you use the ip instead of the new domain that you forgot to change?

Comment: Sounds like you've got some bogus redirect coded in your server's configuration. You should post the relevant parts of your `httpd.conf` and any `.htaccess` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up A records, not forwarding records. You can find GoDaddy's help on the subject here: http://help.godaddy.com/article/680#arecs

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue. To resolve I had to go to "DNS Management" where "A" was marked as "@" and "Forwarded" (if not change it) then below there is a "Forwarding" section where if you click on the pencil it allows you to enter the data:

- Forward To: "http://1.1.1.1" (your IP where you forward to)
- Forward Type: Permanent(301)
- Settings: **HERE WAS MY PROBLEM**: it was set as "Forward Only" and I changed it to "***Forward with masking***" and that fixed the issue

Comment: this just opens your page in an iframe (browser window within a browser window). Modern browsers will block any redirects from an iframe so your page will not be very usable with masking.